# A List of Recursive Data Structure as Function Input

Tags: haskell, types

I defined a recursive data structure in Haskell:

```
data NestedList a = Element a | SubList [NestedList a]
```

and then I want to define a `flatten` function which will take a list of NestedList and return the flattened result, for example:

```
Input: [Element 1, SubList [Element 2, SubList [] ]]
Output: [Element 1, Element 2].
```

However, my definition of function is not correct:

```
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Element a) = [a]
flatten (SubList (x:xs)) = flatten x ++ flatten (SubList xs)
flatten (SubList []) = []
```

According to this definition, my function will work like:

```
flatten (SubList [Element 1, SubList []])
```

instead of

```
flatten [Element 1, SubList []]
```

So this `flatten` cannot take the input I mentioned above, so how should I define `flatten` to make it take input like [Element 1, SubList [Element 2, SubList [] ]]?

Comment: In what way is that not the definition you want? It seems to me that it works just fine - the result would be `[1]`, and if you want to wrap each element of that result in `Element` (for whatever reason...) then just do `map Element . flatten`.

Comment: A simpler, equivalent definition would be to replace the last two clauses with `flatten (Sublist xs) = xs >>= flatten`.

Comment: FWIW, `NestedList` is just `Free []`, and `flatten` is just `toList` from `instance Foldable f => Foldable (Free f)` and `instance Foldable []`.

Comment: if that is not what you want, what do you want?

Comment: I mean I need to take an input like [Element 1, SubList []] instead of SubList [Element 1, SubList []].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for the following:

```
flatten :: [NestedList a] -> [NestedList a]
flatten (Element a  : rest) = Element a : flatten rest
flatten (SubList xs : rest) = flatten xs ++ flatten rest
flatten [] = []
```

which appears to do what you want:

```
> flatten [Element 1, SubList []]
[Element 1]
> flatten [Element 1, SubList [Element 2, SubList []]]
[Element 1,Element 2]
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten your `NestedList` into a flat `NestedList` instead of a normal list, you can define a separate function `fromList :: [a] -> NestedList a` that builds a flat nested list from a normal list.

```
fromList :: [a] -> NestedList a
fromList l = SubList (toElems l)
  where
    toElems :: [a] -> [SubList a]
    toElems (x:xs) = Element x : toElems xs
    toElems [] = []
```

or simply

```
fromList = SubList . map Element
```

and write

```
flattenNested :: NestedList a -> NestedList a
flattenNested = fromList . flatten
```

Of course, you can also write `flatten` itself more simply as:

```
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Element a) = [a]
flatten (SubList xs) = concat (map flatten xs)
```

or even one of these increasingly nerdy substitutes:

```
flatten (SubList xs) = concatMap flatten xs
```

Since `concatMap` is the same as `=<<`:

```
flatten (SubList xs) = flatten =<< xs
```

Since `NestedList` is isomorphic to `Free []`:

```
flatten :: Free [] a -> [a]
flatten (Pure a) = [a]
flatten (Free xs) = flatten =<< xs
```

Or by (ab)using this relationship even further:

```
flatten :: Free [] a -> [a]
flatten = toList
```